# How to resolve degardation high response time on AEM Author server

Tags: aem

When team will execute a test of performance on AEM Pre prod author servers then immediately author server load is increase highly and response time getting more time on server. so here we need a solution for how to reduce this author server response time when test cases are executing.

Comment: Author server is running on CQ5

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this question is way too broad to be answered in a StackOverflow format. You'll need to determine the limiting resources. Is it CPU? Memory? Disk IO? Find out what causes the slowdown. Memory leak? Inefficient custom code? Slow queries with no index? Calls to an external service that's slow to respond? There are hundreds of things that may be going wrong and hundreds of ways you could improve performance. Start by reading through https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/deploying/configuring/configuring-performance.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Add a dispatcher in front of the author server. Though usually intended for publish instances, dispatchers can be setup for authors as well, and alleviate the load on the server returning common files. Of course, make sure to configure it properly to avoid caching editable content.